# Android Deeplinking from Email Client (Cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, email, ionic-framework, deeplink

I have a Cordova based application that i have implemented deeplinks. These deeplinks are working perfectly fine for me in all platforms for me as far as the 'opening up the app is concerned'.

In the native Android email application when links are clicked Im running into a few problems:

- First is that the app takes an extremely long time to load. I dont run into this issue opening the deeplinks from any other context.
- Second is no way to get back to my email client. The device back button does nothing and the only way i can find to get back is to terminate my email client and re-open it.
- Third, somehow when these links are clicked beyond the above two issues it is allowing me to have TWO versions of my app running at the same time. One inside the email client.. and one outside. [See image loading in email client and separate instance outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrV8A.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had to update my project to allow only a single version of it to run.

Adding in:

```
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
```

To my config.xml file (which will place android:launchMode="singleTask" into the AndroidManifest.xml when building android) got things working properly for me.